# Installing Prism in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: prism

I need to install the Prismv4.exe dll on my machine which has visual studio 2010 installed already on it...so, Please help me with the steps for installing it..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Prismv4.exe will extract whole code on you machine. If want to use Prism in you application you have add reference to supporting DLL.